# Getting userID's through their username. Discord.JS

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

```
     client.on("message", async message =>{
      message.guild.members.fetch({query: "username here", limit: 1})
       .then( members => console.log(members.user.id)) //results in undefined
       .catch(console.error);
      }
```

I would like to be able to get a users ID through their username. In this case I use the "fetch()" method and a query within it. However when i try to log (members.user.id) I get "undefined". The thing is whenever i fetch by a user ID(see code below) I am able to access the users ID,username, etc.. How would I able to fetch by their username and then be able to get a users ID. I was using this as a reference point https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=fetch

If theirs an easier way to get a users ID by their username please do tell.

```
     client.on("message", async message =>{
       message.guild.members.fetch("userID here")
       .then( members => console.log(members.user.username))// a username is logged
       .catch(console.error);
             }
```

Comment: Log what member is and show the result. I'm guessing it's not undefined since there would be an error by accessing `.user.id`

Comment: When I log "member" when fetching by username it logs  2 objects ("guild" and "user" objects) of the expected user id. example of what is logged:  Collection [Map] {
  '258444571640463360' => GuildMember { guild: Guild{ "bunch of information here"} user: User{ bunch of information here}}           This is expected but i dont understand why i cant access these objects, when i try to (ex: members.user.id) it says "cannot read property 'id' of undefined"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like even if the limit is 1 it will still give back a collection, so you will need to get the first member of that collection

```js
message.guild.members.fetch({query: "username here", limit: 1})
   .then(members => {
      const member = members.first();
      //no need to convert it into a user 
      console.log(member.id);
   });
```

Comment: Thank you this solved the issue. I didnt take into consideration it being a collection.